PostgreSQL - Bulk COPY slower with unlogged tables than logged tables
We have an ETL process that starts with loading data into PostgresSQL 16.2 databases (Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible). We load 100,000 records at a time using COPY FROM STDIN. This is staging data that doesn't need to be recovered in case of a crash. Because of this, we decided to give unlogged tables a try to reduce costs and increase performance.
My issue is that with all other things being equal, simply adding 'UNLOGGED' to the create table statements increased load times by 30-35% in testing (~21 minutes up to ~28 minutes in one instance, ~31 minutes up to ~41 minutes in another). This doesn't make much sense given what I've read about unlogged tables. Indexes are only created after the data has been loaded into the tables. Overall IOPS to disk and bandwidth consumption are both down when using UNLOGGED. My write throughput (bytes/sec) is much lower with unlogged tables, but I'm not sure if that's a result of having fewer writes in the first place due to not hitting the WAL.
Everything I find online simply talks about "use unlogged tables for faster writes", but there is essentially zero information about what could cause using unlogged tables to result in slower writes. Are there any recommendations for optimizing the performance of bulk loading into unlogged tables? I realize I haven't provided a ton of specifics, but given the lack of information on what can cause this decrease in performance, I don't really know what specific information would be helpful at this point.
Happy to provide any addition information that I can. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

That should not happen with PostgreSQL. Set track_io_timing to on and collect the result of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, WAL, SETTINGS) for both queries. Add that to the question.

@LaurenzAlbe Can EXPLAIN be used with COPY FROM STDIN? Information I've found points to that not being possible.

You are right, that is not possible. Then you have no way to figure this out. To be honest, I find that hard to believe anyway. Did you try the operation several times to get reliable timing?

@LaurenzAlbe I've run the same load a number of times and it is consistently that 30-35% slower. I agree it makes no sense, but it has repeatably been the case.

The only difference between the executions is the inclusion of "UNLOGGED" in the table creation command. All other code is exactly the same.

Have you tried on another local machine? Is the Azure throttling?

We use Azure Batch to load each file in its own task. The nodes process the raw data (with a minimal amount of transformation) and then COPY that data over to the PostgreSQL flexible server database. Even when only running a single job in an effort to minimize load on the server for testing, writing to logged tables is measurably faster for some reason.

That seems very odd indeed. I cannot think of a single corner case that would make unlogged tables slower.

Can you reproduce the issue when running against community PostgreSQL, not Azure?
